# Do i need to use PHP in making this kind of Tax Calculator?

Tags: php, database

I have here a sample Tax Calculator:

http://birtaxcalculator.com/calculators/bir_withholding_tax_computation_2009

as an experienced web developer and about to replicate the same exact calculator, Do you need to use a database to store all the Income tax rates? See the image below.

**Tax rates**
[image]

any advice from the experts..
Thank you.

Comment: I don't see why this couldn't also be done in JavaScript.

Comment: The thing with a database, when it DOES actually change, you can have a nice interface to update the values rather than changing code. It is not needed though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's certainly not required. It's not a very large table, and doesn't change frequently, so I see no reason to build anything that heavy-weight. You could probably just store it in a PHP array, or a flat file like JSON or XML.

Comment: Thanks for the -1 with no comment... Everybody's an anonymous critic.

Comment: clowns, I swear..so brave behind their keyboards

Comment: thanks adrian, you're very helpful. I'm still a beginner and studying php through lynda.com so I'm still figuring out what's the best way to do this.

Comment: @KareenLagasca check http://net.tutsplus.com/ they have some good tutorials on ways you could make this

Comment: I haven't downvoted you answer, but I can see why someone who want that: this is not an answer. You are basically listing all the possibility one has to store data without even list the pro and the cons of each one. Also this is a very broad and non constructive question and answering this kind of questions encourages new people to actually post more.

Answer (score 1):

You could use any language you feel comfortable with. You could hardcode rates in JS and never use a database. You could very easily create a database though, which could keep track of historical rates over a certain period of time.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to implement this functionality on JavaScript . You can store this data directly in arrays or in objects. It will be the faster solution and all data will be calculated on client side.

If you have to provide administration interface for this data management or secure the data from this table from the user, you have to use database with some server scripting language (e.g. Php and MySQL). It will be much slower than JS approach.